# Create Karma 'inlined' plugin

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner

Can anyone explain how Karma inlined plugins work?

The [docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/plugins.html) helpfully say:

```
plugins: [
  // Karma will require() these plugins
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-chrome-launcher'
  // inlined plugins
  {'framework:xyz', ['factory', factoryFn]},
  require('./plugin-required-from-config')
]
```

But do not explain how this is used. I can see from other plugins that the format seems to be:

```
{'<x>:<name>', ['<y>', myFunction]}
```

And that x seems to be one of 'framework', 'preprocessor', 'reporter' or 'launcher' and that y is related to x, but can there be any other types? What do each of them need? How do they relate to the tests?

In my tests I would really like the ability to refer to "myFunction" somehow (I know I *could* include a JS file in the files section, but that would be very complex in my case) - is this possible?

Comment: I came across this problem. Did you solve it?